# Set tabindex for specified fields in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my script like this,

```
$("button, input[readonly='readonly'], input[disabled='disabled'], a, input[type='button']").each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
});
```

This would not focus the mentioned elements while pressing tab key.

And I also do dynamic `readonly=false` and `readonly=true` on the input fields.

My doubt here is how do I set tabindex for rest of the elements(like normal text boxes using jquery) can we not select using if - else on the above statement but I am not sure ?

How do I fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean by not selecting?

```
/* Selects any element that is NOT a paragraph */
:not(p) {
  color: blue;
}
```

see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```
//it should work like :
input:not([readonly='readonly']) {/*...*/}
```